# How to Change Location of User input (Java)?

Tags: java, input

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CurrencyConverter
{
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {        
        Scanner pesos = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the current exchange rate for pesos to dollars?");

        System.out.println();
        Scanner yen = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the current exchange rate for yen to dollars?");

        System.out.println();
        Scanner euros = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the current exchange rate for euros to dollars?");
    }
}
```

What do I add to change from

[image]

to

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Use one `Scanner` and use `Scanner#nextLine` to read a response from the user when ever you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create three variables `Scanner`. Just use one of them and use `input.nextLine();` where `input` it's the variable of the type `Scanner`. Then you can store it in three `String` variables.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CurrencyConverter
{
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String pesos;
        System.out.println("What is the current exchange rate for pesos to dollars?");
        pesos = input.nextLine();

        String yen;
        System.out.println("What is the current exchange rate for yen to dollars?");
        yen = input.nextLine();

        String euros;
        System.out.println("What is the current exchange rate for euros to dollars?");
        euros = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```